# parsing xml in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I am trying to read a XML file in jquery and then use dom manipulation on it. But whenever I parse my xml using $.parseXML(xml) it gives me null object. Please help me in this regard.

My jquery code is as follows:

```
var main=function() {
console.log("hi there");
var $xml;

  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "xml/test.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function (xml) {
        console.log(xml);
        var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml);
        console.log(xmlDoc);
        $xml = $(xmlDoc);
        console.log($xml);
        }
   });
};


$(document).ready(main);
```

my output is as follows:
[image]

My test.xml file is as follows :

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<doc>
    <person>
        <name>sachin</name>
        <age>21</age>
    </person>
    <person>
        <name>Akash</name>
        <age>18</age>
    </person>
</doc>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing `dataType: "xml"` tells jQuery to call `parseXML` for you.

You don't need to do anything.